# Cannot change Diigo highlight color when it has a sticky note

Tags: diigo, highlight

In Diigo, we can highlight text and add a sticky note to that highlighted text.

I cannot find a way to change the highlight's color after adding a sticky note to it.

Is there a solution to this?

Please share.

[Update]
I've tested and on Firefox we can change it; on Chrome we cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what works for me on a Mac using Firefox.

1. Mouse over the note indicator.
2. When your note appears, there's a little "Edit" menu in the bottom left, shown with a pencil icon. Click it.
3. A menu appears. (For some reason, mine's a little far away from the note.)
4. Pick the color you want to change to.
5. Done.

(I don't have enough rep to post an image yet, but [I've posted a series of screen grabs showing these steps](http://james.da.ydrea.ms/diigo_change_highlight_color.png).)

Comment: Works in firefox. Though, doesn't work for me. I'm using Chrome